# Bing maps Soap Services

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am developing an application for phone 7 using Bingmap soap services.The application works fine and good.
But sometimes i get an exception in Bingmap Soap services that "endpoint not found".When i hit the service on a browser it works well and good.
Is there anything like  that "number of hits to bingmap soap services on a particular day".
Please help me with this issue.I am getting this exceotion after 1-2 days.

Exception details
"There was no endpoint listening at http://dev.virtualearth.net/webservices/v1/geocodeservice/GeocodeService.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details."

Comment: and was there an innerexception? Are you certain you had conenctivity at that time?

Comment: wow no answer since Jun... did you find a way to fix this problem?